# Checking for the first value of data frame and assigning a value in Python

Tags: python, pandas

r is a dataframe with five columsn i,j,k,l,m

Below is my code,

```
   for i in pd.unique(r.id):
        sub=r[(r.id==i)] //subsetting the dataframe for each ID
        sub=sub.drop_duplicates(["i","j","k","l","m"]) // dropping the duplicates
        sub['k']=pd.to_datetime(sub['k'],unit='s',utc=False)
        g=int(sub.iloc[0]['m']) // want to get the first value of the column
        if g>64:

            r=(g/64)-1
        else:
            r=0
        if(len(sub)>1):
           sub.m=r*64 + m
```

This works well for one ID. When there are multiple IDs, I am getting,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/project1/Final.py", line 90, in <module>
    sub=r[(r.id==i)]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Can anybody help me in solving this problem? I want to loop for all the IDs in r dataframe so that I can make some calculations.

Comment: In this line `r=(g/64)-1` you're overwriting the dataframe `r` with an integer. Choose a different variable name for that.

Comment: @bernie Thank you.. It was a silly mistake from my side. But have been spending a lot of time in this :(

Comment: Don't beat yourself up about it. We've all made this kind of mistake at least once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the for loop you overwrite the dataframe r with an int:

```
if g>64:
    r=(g/64)-1
else:
    r=0
```

This is fine with one ID because on the first iteration r is still a dataframe.

It fails with multiple IDs because on the second iteration it has been overwritten by the int, and throws the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Silly Mistake it was :(